# Forms Authentication on Restful

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, restful-authentication, wcf-rest

Scenario of the topic....

First user enters his credentials from a mobile app and i get the data in hash code format and hit the RESTful webservice..

Now i need to decrypt the data and pass the data to a dll file where all the username and passwords are stored...

From the dll file i get whether credentials r authorized or not....

Now the questions is can we use the forms authentication for this whole scenario...If we use wht are the pros and corns??????.....

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a custom username password validator that calls your custom DLL for authentication.  Forms authentication doesn't seem like a fit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

Make sure your custom authentication DLL is thread safe, otherwise you might run into problems once you get multiple concurrent requests coming into the service.